# How do I add public screens to react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am building a react-native app using Expo and react-navigation, the app currently has two navigators, one is visible to authenticated users and one is only visible to unauthenticated users, like the sign-in page.

Here is the navigation structure:

```js
function Navigation({ isLoggedIn }) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home}></Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="public" component={Public}></Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login}></Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen name="public" component={Public}></Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

as you can see there is a screen called 'public' that appears twice in both navigators because I want people to be able to view this component regardless of their authentication status, **is this the correct way to do it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initiating two separate Stack Navigator based on `isLoggedIn` state, what you can do is initiating one Stack Navigator and then put screens based on `isLoggedIn` state. Like the following

```
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          
          {isLoggedIn ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home}></Stack.Screen>
          ) : (
            <Stack.Screen name="login" component={Login}></Stack.Screen>
          )}
          
          <Stack.Screen name="public" component={Public}></Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

In this way, you don't have to put the 'public' screen twice but users can see that screen regardless of their authentication status. Also, you don't have to initiate StackNavigator twice.

Comment: @R.Shen, if the answer helps, don't forget to 'accept' the answer :)

Comment: @R.Shen, no worries, keep trying. If you face any problem, then we are here for you. :)